# Apply for UK Student Visa in Non Home Country

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am an American citizen currently residing in Madrid, Spain on a student visa (one year durations). I have been living in Spain for the past three years. I have been accepted to study a master's program in London beginning in September.

Would it be possible for me to apply for a UK student visa (PBS/Tier 4) from Spain?

I wrote to the UK Visa and Immigration International Enquiry Office and they directed me to this link (https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy) that states applications "should be made in the country in which you are living".

Does having a year long student visa qualify me as "living" in Spain? I am also a registered resident with the municipal town hall if that helps. My Spanish visa expires the beginning of July but I plan to apply for the UK student visa at the end of June.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it is possible to apply for any category of U.K. visa from any country where there is a consulate/visa processing office. The only requirement is that the applicant must be present legally in the country or territory they’re applying from. So yes, you should be able to apply from Spain before your student visa expires. You might however want to check visa processing times in case the application takes longer than the time you’d have left on your Spanish visa.